# GPUImage + Touch Blurring effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I need to implement a touch blur effect in my app.  I'm using [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/) for basic filtering but I also need to include the ability to blur any area in the image.  I've struggled for a few days on this and couldn't find any other questions/answers that helped.

My current (pseudocode) implementation, which doesn't take advantage of GPUImage is as follows:

```
In the pan gesture recognizer, I'm collecting the pan gesture objects and saving them to an array.  When UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded, I attempt to apply the blur using:

1. Get image from GPUImagePicture.
2. Create a "CIGaussianBlur" CIFilter to create a blurred image.
3. Loop through the gesture taps
4. Create a CIFilter mask with a CIRadialGradient with the location as center.
5. Composite the masks into 1 mask: 
maskImage = [[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing" keysAndValues:
             kCIInputImageKey, gassBlur, kCIInputBackgroundImageKey, maskImage, nil] valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

6. Crop the mask:
CIVector *rect = [CIVector vectorWithCGRect:origImage.extent];
maskImage = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CICrop" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, maskImage, @"inputRectangle", rect, nil].outputImage;

7. Use a CIBlendWithMask filter to combine the original image, the mask, and the blurred image:
CIFilter *blendedFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBlendWithMask" keysAndValues:
                           @"inputImage", pixellateFilter.outputImage,
                           @"inputBackgroundImage", origImage,
                           @"inputMaskImage", maskImage,
                           nil];

8. Update the image view with the new image:
[self.tempImgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCIImage:pixellateFilter.outputImage]];
```

How can I make the blur effect real-time, as if the user is "painting" the image with a blurring brush?  A perfect example of this is the app [Touch Blur](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/touch-blur/id545958271).

**EDIT 1:**

My filter chain is like this:

```
[self.staticPicture addTarget:self.filter]; // self.filter is some B&W, sepia, etc filter
[self.filter addTarget:self.blurFilter];    // I think the blur filter should be modified somehow
[self.blurFilter addTarget:self.gpuImageView];
[self.staticPicture processImage];
```

I need to update self.blurFilter in the pan gesture event somehow and then call processImage each time to update the gpuImageView.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using a box blur in my app, [You Doodle](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id517871755?mt=8&uo=4&at=10l5Hs) that is done entirely on the CPU. Assuming you have the raw pixels for your image, you can blur the necessary pixels and then perform a drawRect and then draw the rect that was blurred to a UIView. The blur is even decently fast on an iPhone 4S with a 4 megapixel image, and runs buttery smooth on iPad 2 and newer.

Box blur library: https://github.com/gdawg/uiimage-dsp